# How to apply switchMap for (click) Angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following element clik:

```
<div *ngFor="let doc in docs">
<app-checkbox (onSelected)="onSelectedDocument(doc, $event)"                                           [disabled]="isApprepdocsDisabled(doc)"
[checked]="doc.isapprepdocs == 1"
[id]="doc.index"></app-checkbox>
</div>
```

And handler of event:

```
    public closed$ = new Subject<any>();
    public documentChecked$ = new Subject<any>();

  ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.documentChecked$
            .pipe(
                exhaustMap((data: { docid: number; checked: boolean }) =>
                    iif(
                        () => data.checked,
                        this.applicationDocumentsService.addtoappdoc(data.docid),
                        this.applicationDocumentsService.removefromappdoc(data.docid),
                    ),
                ),
                takeUntil(this.closed$),
            )
            .subscribe(
                (res) => {
                    console.log(res);
                },
                (err) => {},
            );
    }
```

Why after server error the next click does not emit values?

Comment: Where does the `checked` value come from?

Comment: Could you please elaborate? What is the "_sendinf reqyest_"? Where is it called in the `onSelectedDocument()` function?

Comment: Yes, I need to prevent next request until resoosne comes

Answer (score 1):

You could RxJS [`iif`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/iif) function to select an observable based on a condition. Try the following

```js
public onSelectedDocument(doc: any, checked: boolean): void {
  iif(
    () => checked,
    this.applicationDocumentsService.addtoappdoc(doc.docid),
    this.applicationDocumentsService.removefromappdoc(doc.docid)
  ).subscribe(
    res => { },
    err => { }
  )
}
```

### Update: ignore events until current event complete ###

To ignore the incoming events you need to use `exhaustMap` mapping operator. `switchMap` is actually the exact opposite of what you require. It'll cancel the current requests when new events are emitted.

Also you could remove the `(click)` event binding in the template and use the `ViewChild` with RxJS `fromEvent` function to get `click` events from the `div` element. Try the following

Template

```html
<div #clickDiv>Click</div>
```

Controller

```js
import { Component, OnInit, OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { iif, fromEvent, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil, exhaustMap } from 'rxjs';

export class SomeComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  closed$ = new Subject<any>();    // <-- use to close subscriptions 
  @ViewChild('clickDiv', { static: false }) clickDiv: ElementRef<any>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    fromEvent(this.clickDiv.nativeElement, 'click').pipe(
      exhaustMap(_ =>              // <-- ignore incoming events until the current event is complete
        iif(
          () => checked,
          this.applicationDocumentsService.addtoappdoc(doc.docid),
          this.applicationDocumentsService.removefromappdoc(doc.docid)
        )
      ),
      takeUntil(this.closed$)
    ).subscribe(
      res => { },
      err => { }
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.closed$.next();            // <-- close open subscriptions
  }
}
```

#### Update: handle events from multiple DOM elements

If you're having multiple DOM elements, please ignore the previous update. For multiple elements you actually need to use `ViewChildren`. You could continue to use the `onSelected` event, but instead of calling an event-handler, you could push the event to a multi-cast observable (like a RxJS `Subject`). It could then be subscribe with an `exhaustMap` operator piped in between. Try the following

Template

```html
<div *ngFor="let doc in docs">
  <app-checkbox 
    (onSelected)="docClick$.next(doc)"
    [disabled]="isApprepdocsDisabled(doc)"
    [checked]="doc.isapprepdocs == 1"
    [id]="doc.index"
  ></app-checkbox>
</div>
```

Controller

```js
import { Component, OnInit, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

import { iif, Subject, of } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil, exhaustMap, catchError } from 'rxjs';

export class SomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  closed$ = new Subject<any>();    // <-- use to close subscriptions
  docClick$ = new Subject<any>();  // <-- event handler for doc click events

  ngOnInit() {
    this.docClick$.asObservable().pipe(
      exhaustMap(doc =>            // <-- ignore incoming events until the current event is complete
        iif(
          () => checked,
          this.applicationDocumentsService.addtoappdoc(doc['docid']),
          this.applicationDocumentsService.removefromappdoc(doc['docid'])
        )
      ),
      catchError(error =>          // <-- return valid response if error so the subscription doesn't error out
        of(error)
      ),
      takeUntil(this.closed$)
    ).subscribe(
      res => { },
      err => { }
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.closed$.next();            // <-- close open subscriptions
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not work as swithMap, I can click some times

Comment: Do you want to disable the click event until the subscription is complete?

Comment: Yes, I want, not allow next request until get response

Comment: `switchMap` does the exact opposite of what you actually require. You need to use `exhaustMap` to ignore the incoming events until the current event is complete. I've updated the answer. Please see if it works for you.

Comment: Wht if i have some `<div #clickDiv>Click</div>`? It is some checkboxes

Comment: You could replace `<div>` with the checkbox `<input>`s. Please show the actual code if you require appropriate answer.

Comment: Also I get an error: `Property 'docid' does not exist on type 'unknown'.`

Comment: Use bracket notation `doc['docid']` instead of dot notation `doc.docid`. And what is the `documentCheckObs` that you're subscribing to in the question?

Comment: Sorry for my mess, I have updated a question, it is final

Comment: @user13314476: I've updated the answer. Please see if it works.

Comment: It does not work second time  if resposne is not 200

Comment: @user13314476: That is separate question. You need to handle the error using `catchError` so the subscription doesn't error out. There are many questions in SO already related to that topic. I've updated the answer.

Comment: No matter, still not working, when Ihave added eror catch